# Oracle Installed Operating system

Tags: oracle

how to check oracle database has installed which operating system?.Currently I'm working in remote server, I don't know my oracle server running in windows os or linux os. How can I identify, If any query is there?. If yes, Please share to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`PORT_STRING`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i997419) function:

> This function returns a string that identifies the operating system and the TWO TASK PROTOCOL version of the database. For example, "VAX/VMX-7.1.0.0"

```
select dbms_utility.port_string from dual;
```

Comment: The result is SVR4-be-64bit-8.1.0
Whether It's Windows or Linux?

Comment: Seems like Solaris. You could also query `v$version` for more information.